# In Constructor ClassName::ClassName() ... ClassName doesn't have any field named 'VariableName'

Tags: c++, class, oop, polymorphism, multiple-inheritance

I'm dealing with an issue right now in C++, where I have a defined variable existing within my class definition, the compiler gets angry and tells me that said variable has not been defined within the scope, and that the constructor doesn't have any field for the variable in question.

I have a simple class hierarchy where I have the base class, `Neuron`, and two subclasses `HiddenNeuron` and `OutputNeuron`, that are both inheriting from `Neuron` in `public virtual` mode.

I've made a `neuron.h` file where I defined the virtual header class, and as such, I have been told by my instructor that I need not write an implementation file for it.

I've then written two header files for `HiddenNeuron` and `OutputNeuron`, in which I define them, and two corresponding cpp files that implement them, respectively.

When I try running

> g++ neuralnet.cpp input_neuron.cpp hidden_neuron.cpp output_neuron.cpp

I get a bunch of errors like:

> hidden_neuron.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void HiddenNeuron::input(long double)’:
>      hidden_neuron.cpp:10:52: error: ‘value’ was not declared in this scope
>       inline void HiddenNeuron::input(double long val) { value = val; }

and

> hidden_neuron.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void   HiddenNeuron::input(long double)’:
>      hidden_neuron.cpp:10:52: error: ‘value’ was not declared in this scope
>       inline void HiddenNeuron::input(double long val) { value = val; }

Here's the code for my classes:

neuron.h:

```
#ifndef NEURON_H
#define NEURON_H

class Neuron {
  //protected:
  //  double long value;
 public:
  Neuron(void);
  //Neuron(const double long val);

  // 
  virtual double long activation(void) const =0;

  virtual void input(double long val);
};


#endif
```

output_neuron.h:

```
#ifndef OUTPUT_NEURON_H
#define OUTPUT_NEURON_H
#include "neuron.h"

class OutputNeuron : public virtual Neuron {
 private:
  double long value;
 public:
  OutputNeuron(void);
  OutputNeuron(const double long val);

  // this should return a value between 0 & 1
  virtual double long activation(void) const;

  // vector multiplication of the weight vector
  // and all the values of the last layer
  // with an additional corresponding bias
  // added onto the end.
  virtual void input(double long val);
};

#endif
```

output_neuron.cpp:

```
#include "output_neuron.h"
#include <cmath>

OutputNeuron::OutputNeuron(void) : value(0) { }

OutputNeuron::OutputNeuron(const double long val)
  : value(val) { }

inline double long OutputNeuron::activation(void) const {
  return 1 / (1 + exp((-1)*value));
}

inline void OutputNeuron::input(double long val) {
  value = val;
}
```

hidden_neuron.h:

```
#ifndef HIDDEN_NEURON_H
#define HIDDEN_NEURON_H
#include "neuron.h"

class HiddenNeuron : public virtual Neuron {
 private:
  double long value;
 public:
  HiddenNeuron(void);
  HiddenNeuron(const double long val);

  // activation function that takes the stored value
  // and squashes it and returns it
  virtual double long activation(void) const;

  virtual void input(double long val);
};

#endif
```

hidden_neuron.cpp:

```
#include "hidden_neuron.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

HiddenNeuron::HiddenNeuron(void)
  : value(pow(-1, rand()) * static_cast<double>(rand())/static_cast<double>(RAND_MAX)){}

HiddenNeuron::HiddenNeuron(const double long val) : value(val) { }

inline void HiddenNeuron::input(double long val) { value = val; }

inline double long HiddenNeuron::activation(void) const {
  return 1/(1 + exp((-1)*value));
}
```

**FULL ERROR LOG:**

```
neuralnet.cpp: In member function ‘void NeuralNet::initialize(bool)’:
neuralnet.cpp:72:18: error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type ‘HiddenNeuron’
       temp = new HiddenNeuron;
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from neuralnet.h:5:0,
                 from neuralnet.cpp:1:
hidden_neuron.h:5:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘HiddenNeuron’:
 class HiddenNeuron : public virtual Neuron {
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from hidden_neuron.h:3:0,
                 from neuralnet.h:5,
                 from neuralnet.cpp:1:
neuron.h:14:16: note:   virtual void Neuron::input(long double) const
   virtual void input(double long val) const =0;
                ^~~~~
neuralnet.cpp:85:18: error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type ‘HiddenNeuron’
       temp = new HiddenNeuron;
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
neuralnet.cpp:98:18: error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type ‘OutputNeuron’
       temp = new OutputNeuron;
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from neuralnet.h:7:0,
                 from neuralnet.cpp:1:
output_neuron.h:5:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘OutputNeuron’:
 class OutputNeuron : public virtual Neuron {
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from hidden_neuron.h:3:0,
                 from neuralnet.h:5,
                 from neuralnet.cpp:1:
neuron.h:14:16: note:   virtual void Neuron::input(long double) const
   virtual void input(double long val) const =0;
                ^~~~~
hidden_neuron.cpp: In constructor ‘HiddenNeuron::HiddenNeuron()’:
hidden_neuron.cpp:6:5: error: class ‘HiddenNeuron’ does not have any field named ‘value’
   : value(pow(-1, rand()) * static_cast<double>(rand())/static_cast<double>(RAND_MAX)){}
     ^~~~~
hidden_neuron.cpp: In constructor ‘HiddenNeuron::HiddenNeuron(long double)’:
hidden_neuron.cpp:8:53: error: class ‘HiddenNeuron’ does not have any field named ‘value’
 HiddenNeuron::HiddenNeuron(const double long val) : value(val) { }
                                                     ^~~~~
hidden_neuron.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void HiddenNeuron::input(long double)’:
hidden_neuron.cpp:10:52: error: ‘value’ was not declared in this scope
 inline void HiddenNeuron::input(double long val) { value = val; }
                                                    ^~~~~
hidden_neuron.cpp:10:52: note: suggested alternative: ‘val’
 inline void HiddenNeuron::input(double long val) { value = val; }
                                                    ^~~~~
                                                    val
hidden_neuron.cpp: In member function ‘virtual long double HiddenNeuron::activation() const’:
hidden_neuron.cpp:13:26: error: ‘value’ was not declared in this scope
   return 1/(1 + exp((-1)*value));
                          ^~~~~
hidden_neuron.cpp:13:26: note: suggested alternative: ‘valloc’
   return 1/(1 + exp((-1)*value));
                          ^~~~~
                          valloc
output_neuron.cpp: In constructor ‘OutputNeuron::OutputNeuron()’:
output_neuron.cpp:4:36: error: class ‘OutputNeuron’ does not have any field named ‘value’
 OutputNeuron::OutputNeuron(void) : value(0) { }
                                    ^~~~~
output_neuron.cpp: In constructor ‘OutputNeuron::OutputNeuron(long double)’:
output_neuron.cpp:7:5: error: class ‘OutputNeuron’ does not have any field named ‘value’
   : value(val) { }
     ^~~~~
output_neuron.cpp: In member function ‘virtual long double OutputNeuron::activation() const’:
output_neuron.cpp:10:28: error: ‘value’ was not declared in this scope
   return 1 / (1 + exp((-1)*value));
                            ^~~~~
output_neuron.cpp:10:28: note: suggested alternative: ‘valloc’
   return 1 / (1 + exp((-1)*value));
                            ^~~~~
                            valloc
output_neuron.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void OutputNeuron::input(long double)’:
output_neuron.cpp:14:3: error: ‘value’ was not declared in this scope
   value = val;
   ^~~~~
output_neuron.cpp:14:3: note: suggested alternative: ‘val’
   value = val;
   ^~~~~
   val
```

If anyone can help me, I've been pulling my hair out with this issue.

**Edit:** using class design as it's a requirement for the course I'm currently enrolled in.

**Edit 2:** included the full error log

**Edit 3:** Okay so this is really bizarre, what I wrote works in a separate project directory as pointed out by user idontseethepoint, however when it's in the same directory as my main project, it still gives me the exact same error.

Comment: Remove the `inline` keywords in the cpp file

Comment: that doesn't help at all, the errors still persist. Not to mention that the function is going to be called numerous times, so doing so would do nothing but create unnecessary overhead.

Comment: This compiles and runs: https://ideone.com/ShrYKs Did you define Neuron::input(double long val)?

Comment: yea I did, but they're all in separate files. I'm not sure if that's incorrect.

Comment: Also the problem with what you posted is that you're inheriting `neuron` in `public` mode, not `public virtual`, which is what I need in order to prevent there from being multiple instances of the same base class.

Comment: From your g++ command it must be defined in neuralnet.cpp, because you've shown the other files and it isn't in any of them

Comment: In the code for the both of the header files of the sub-classes, I commented out an attempt in which I defined `double long value;` in their own classes. This did absolutely nothing, and I continued to get the same results as in the original post.

Comment: I just changed it to public virtual and it worked fine. Virtual inheritance is not necessary here. It would become necessary if you defined a new class that had multiple inheritance from both HiddenNeron and OutputNeuron, because then the new class would inherit from Neuron twice. That isn't happening here, though

Comment: I just tried to create an implementation file for class `Neuron`, and am still receiving the same results. I don't know if I made this clear but **all my classes have seperate header and implementation files** 
` g++ neuralnet.cpp neuron.cpp input_neuron.cpp hidden_neuron.cpp output_neuron.cpp ` still gives me the same errors.

Comment: I can't reproduce this error. It looks like it might be a spelling error. Are you sure you copied it exactly? Also, both errors in your original question are the same. Can you give the exact full error message?

Comment: Yeah, I just updated the question to include the full error log, sorry about that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159870/discussion-between-idontseethepoint-and-oleg-silkin).

Comment: So I replicated the entire project in a separate directory and it compiled and ran perfectly fine, however when I tried compiling the same exact code in the main project directory, it continued to give me the same error of value not being a variable :/

Comment: Okay so it turns out there were .gch files in my directory that were somehow preventing my project from properly compiling. I ran `rm *.gch` and it fixed everything.